# greenDAO 40 seconds to insert 600 records

Tags: android, greendao

I've chosen greenDAO because it's site states that it's one of the fastest ORM systems for android. To my dissapointment it takes it like 40 seconds to insert 600 records on Samsung i9001. I'm not sure if I'm doing anything wrong.

Could you suggest anything to lessen the amount of time it takes to perform those operations ?

generator code:

```
private static void addNewsArticle(Schema schema) {
    Entity article = schema.addEntity("NewsArticle");
    article.addIdProperty().autoincrement();
    article.addStringProperty("title").notNull();
    article.addStringProperty("body").notNull();
    article.addStringProperty("shortDescription").notNull();
    article.addStringProperty("thumb");
    article.addDateProperty("date").notNull();
}
```

insertions

```
Date now = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
for (int i = 0; i < 600; i++) {
    NewsArticle testArticle = new NewsArticle();
    testArticle.setTitle("title-text" + i);
    testArticle.setBody("body-text" + i);
    testArticle.setShortDescription("short-text" + i);
    testArticle.setDate(now);
    newsArticleDao.insert(testArticle);
}
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

As I suspected things weren't executed within a single sql statement. In order to achieve it just use insertInTx on a DAO object.

Here's the above code with slight changes that make it run in like half a second

```
NewsArticle[] newsArticles = new NewsArticle[600];
NewsArticle testArticle;
    for (int i = 0; i < 600; i++) {
         testArticle = new NewsArticle();
         testArticle.setTitle("title-text" + i);
         testArticle.setBody("body-text" + i);
         testArticle.setShortDescription("short-text" + i);
         testArticle.setDate(now);
         newsArticles[i] = testArticle;
    }
newsArticleDao.insertInTx(newsArticles);
```

Comment: you saved my ass in 3 years before.

Comment: I prove the load of my database (from 01:30 min to ~1s). Thanks very much!.

Answer (score 9):

you can also create a new Runnable that does all the inserts runs within the `DaoSession.runInTx` function

```
daoSession.runInTx(new Runnable {
    public void run(){
        Date now = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        for (int i = 0; i < 600; i++) {
             NewsArticle testArticle = new NewsArticle();
                     testArticle.setTitle("title-text" + i);
                     testArticle.setBody("body-text" + i);
                     tesArticle.setShortDescription("short-text" + i);
                     testArticle.setDate(now);
                     newsArticleDao.insert(testArticle);
        }
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

An excellent article on speeding up SQLITE insert operations for Android is given here.
Tryout this I could optimize the sync  modules speed dramatically from 1.2 hours to 14 mins in syncing 39MB DB.

http://tech.vg.no/2011/04/04/speeding-up-sqlite-insert-operations/

Let me know in case if you need code spinnets.

Comment: That is an excellent article, but greenDAO already has optimizations in place for using transactions. User midnight's answer is the best one.

Answer (score 0):

I tried below mentioned and got the best performance

```
        DevOpenHelper helper = new DaoMaster.DevOpenHelper(this, "db-name",
                null);
        SQLiteDatabase dbGreen= helper.getWritableDatabase();

        dbGreen.beginTransaction();

        //Perform your insertion here
        dbGreen.setTransactionSuccessful();
        dbGreen.endTransaction();
```