# Transactions with GreenDao

Tags: android, transactions, greendao

I made this post because I don't understand how transaction works using GreenDao and I would love to get some explanation/recent tutorial.

Despite of reading the [Greendao github](https://github.com/greenrobot/greenDAO/blob/master/examples/RxDaoExample/src/main/java/org/greenrobot/greendao/rxexample/MainActivity.java), I don't understand how the main activity works. For example:

```
...
    Note note = new Note(null, noteText, comment, new Date(), NoteType.TEXT);
    noteDao.insert(note)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Action1<Note>() {
                @Override
                public void call(Note note) {
                    Log.d("DaoExample", "Inserted new note, ID: " + note.getId());
                    updateNotes();
                }
            });
...
```

Do the *observeOn* method sends every insertion/update to one limited buffer? so, it will manage automatically the insertion to the real database when every operation was finished whithout problems?

[Reading its API](http://greenrobot.org/files/greendao/javadoc/3.1/org/greenrobot/greendao/AbstractDaoSession.html#rxTx--), we could see that they use *rxTx* and *rxTxPlain* for transactions (other way?), and [finding out where are performed](https://github.com/greenrobot/greenDAO/blob/master/tests/DaoTest/src/androidTest/java/org/greenrobot/greendao/daotest/DaoSessionConcurrentTest.java), I have to say I misunderstood everything. For example:

```
...
    public void testConcurrentInsertDuringTx() throws InterruptedException {

        ...

        Runnable runnable2 = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                dao.insertInTx(createEntity(null));
            }
        };
        Runnable runnable3 = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                daoSession.runInTx(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        dao.insert(createEntity(null));
                    }
                });
            }
        };

        ...           

        // Builds the statement so it is ready immediately in the thread
        dao.insert(createEntity(null));
        doTx(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                dao.insert(createEntity(null));
            }
        });
        latchThreadsDone.await();
        assertEquals(7, dao.count());
    }
...
```

I know this is an example, **but I don't know the diferences of using the rx methods and the observeOn/subscribe ones**

```
protected void doTx(final Runnable runnableInsideTx) {
    daoSession.runInTx(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            latchInsideTx.countDown();
            // Give the concurrent thread time so it will try to acquire locks
            try {
                Thread.sleep(TIME_TO_WAIT_FOR_THREAD);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            runnableInsideTx.run();
        }
    });
}
```

I read some topics about transactions, but they are obsoletes or maybe, I didn't understand them correctly:

[SQLite transaction behaviour using greendao](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29227054/sqlite-transaction-behaviour-using-greendao)

[Android - Green Dao Multiple Transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32412573/android-green-dao-multiple-transaction)

[Transactions in GreenDao](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25189764/transactions-in-greendao)

[greenDAO 40 seconds to insert 600 records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12748899/greendao-40-seconds-to-insert-600-records)

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/greendao/PXRwCRTbP6c

Someone could help me giving me some explanation/recent tutorial? Greendao have these methods as experimentals. Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you try to shorten your question and state more clearly what exactly you want to know?

Comment: Hi @greenrobot, I only want to know how to use transactions with GreenDao

Comment: In general? Use runInTx(). I just wrote a piece for ObjectBox: http://greenrobot.org/objectbox/documentation/transactions/ The basics should be the same minus read transactions and concurrency.

Comment: Ok, I will read it. Thanks